# Grid View Adapter problems

Tags: android, gridview, textview, imageview

I'm using a GridView adapter for showing images (in R.drawable) and text descriptions under the images (both things are coded in the strings.xml file in a array list). I want to show the image and text in a new activity when clicked on the specific image.

Looking through SO, I found that it's better to use int instead of bitmap for images because of the image size, but I'm having problems with the adapter...

The line: "holder.image.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(0, -1));" as shown below is giving me an error in logcat.

Any advice?

GridViewAdapter code:

```
    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ImageItem> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ImageItem item = data.get(position);
    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    // problem code >>> holder.image.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(0, -1));
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Logcat says "FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException" before pointing to that line of code (GridViewAdapter.getView) that I said is giving problems. App crashes on start.

Answer (score 0):

your getView method should look like this.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ImageItem item = data.get(position);
    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.image.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(0, -1));
    return row;
}
```

your view holder class should look like the following

```
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView imageTitle;
    public ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130338/discussion-on-answer-by-xfighter-grid-view-adapter-problems).